# Syntax error unexpected {

Tags: ruby

I have tried to understand what is the error with this code can you please help me?

```
should_delete = blocked_keywords.any?({|s|x.tweet.downcase.include?(s.downcase)})

(irb):3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end-of-input
....downcase.include?(s.downcase)})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A block is not an argument, an argument is not a block. Parentheses are for arguments, braces are for blocks, you cannot use both at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

`any?` expects a block so parentheses are not needed.

```
should_delete = blocked_keywords.any? {|s|x.tweet.downcase.include?(s.downcase)}
```

Answer (score 1):

should be:

```
should_delete = blocked_keywords.any? {|s| x.tweet.downcase.include?(s.downcase)}
```